# Add vertical units to a DEM in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, geoprocessing, units

I know that this may have been "answered" on other questions, but I am new to ArcGIS Pro, and they did not provide the guidance I need.

I am currently working on a project for a class, and I have to make a suitability map for a hospital in a county. I was going to convert the DEM I was provided to a slope map, but an issue arose: There is no specified Z Factor: The warning by Z Factor will tell me there is no vertical unit for the raster defined.

[image: The warning by Z Factor will tell me there is no vertical unit for the raster defined.]

I checked the properties and I found nothing specified:

[image: No Vertical Unit]

I looked around for a solution, but I found nothing; the "Elevation" tab on properties was promising, but even though it said "vertical unit" there, the geoprocessing tool did not recognize a vertical unit. The Esri help page said to use Define Project, but that is not for rasters; I tried define raster, but nothing there was for vertical units. I found specific articles on vertical units, but in all those cases, the problem was on changing the unit, and not the simple lack of vertical units even specified. I do not even know what to do to add vertical units to the DEM, and I need to add them or else I can not make the slope map.

Comment: Note: I eventually found that there is a tool called Surface Parameter, which allows me to specify vertical units within the tool itself. However, I would still like to know if adding vertical units to the Raster data itself is possible.